# deferred external javascript run twice in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have facing issue with `React.memo` in nextJs. if a component has wrapped with the `React.memo`. when Click event has attached twice. if will remove it then click event attach single. can you help for that?

[image]

page/index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'

function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
        <script defer src="/js/app.js"></script>
      </Head>
      <Accoridion title="title here" description="this is test body."/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Accordion.js

```
const Accordion= ({title ,description}) =>{
     return (
          <>
            <a href="#content-2" class="accordion-toggle">{title}</a>
            <div class="accordion-content" id="content-2">
              {description}
            </div>
          </>
    )
}

export default Memo(Accordion);
```

app.js

```
var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-content');
var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-toggle');
for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
    accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
}
function toggleItem() {
    var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
    for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
        accItem[i].className = 'accordionItem close';
    }
    if (itemClass == 'accordionItem close') {
        this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem open';
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `React.memo` call are you talking about?

Comment: @Bergi, plz check the code above, I have update the code